# How to perform 10 random splits to ensure the consistency of the machine learning result

Tags: python, machine-learning, cross-validation

I just read a paper about image popularity prediction. The author split the data into two halves, one for training and the other testing. 5-fold cross-validation was used on the training set to find the optimal parameters. And the outcome of the experiment is the rank correlation between the predicted popularity and the actual popularity.

To ensure the consistency of the result, the author averaged the performance over 10 random splits. I am confused about the 10 random splits.

- Does it mean when he got the optimal parameters and the model, the model was used on the testing set, and the testing set was split for 10 times and 10 parts, 9 for training and 1 for testing?
- Did the model train again during the process?

Answer (score 1):

Reading up on [What is cross-validation](https://machinelearningmastery.com/k-fold-cross-validation/) should help some.
I cannot speak to what the author did without looking at the paper, but the idea of cross-validation is to not do the splits on the test dataset, but actually train and discard models after doing K splits on the entire dataset, Using each subset once for testing.

Assuming you're okay on that part, the way you worded it makes it sound to me that after choosing the optimal parameters, the person proceeded to start with the 50-50 split from step 1 once again, and this time without changing the parameters, in effect getting a new train and test set. He did this 10 times in total.

IF that is the case, it essentially means that he trained the same model architecture 9 more times after performing the 50-50 split at random on the entire set 9 more times, and averaged out his "performance" metric across the 10 scores.

**EDIT:**
[Paper Reference](https://people.csail.mit.edu/khosla/papers/www2014_khosla.pdf)

> **3.2 Evaluation** For each of the settings described above, we split the data randomly  into  two  halves,  one  for  training  and  the 
>   other testing.  We average the performance over 10 random splits to
>   ensure the consistency of our results; overall, we find that our 
>   results  are  highly  consistent  with  low  standard  devia- tions
>   across splits.

Alright, so yes, the author indeed "repeated" his work 10 times, each time creating a random 50-50 split to start.

So, the essence of it is, the 5 fold cross validation happened during training on the training set. The remaining 50% was used as evaluation. Think of it not like a typical test set, but rather like a "hold-out" set. Since cross validation meant the 50% of data was used both to train and test during the entire process.

At that point, you scrap all your work except the hyperparamaters and the result on the corresponding "hold-out" 50% of data. Now you start with your entire dataset again, and do a different but random 50% split. This time, with the same hyperparameters, you train again on your new training set, and test on your new "hold-out" set for this result. And repeat.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I do know that the cross-validation should be used for selecting the optimal parameter or models. But he used 5 fold cross-validation on the training set to get the optimal parameters. I am confused on which dataset he used the model and which dataset was 10 random splits.

Comment: Here's the link of the paper (https://people.csail.mit.edu/khosla/papers/www2014_khosla.pdf)

Comment: @ZhangQing Updated with the edit, the initial hunch was correct. Let me know if this makes sense

Comment: Ok,I almost understand. Just one more question just for making sure that I totally understand what you explained. The work started from 50-50 split, and 5 fold cross-validation was used on the training set and the optimal parameter was selected. Used the model on the testing set and got outcome. The process repeated another 9 times, the dataset was 50-50 splited, one part for training and another for testing, but the 5 fold cross-validation only did once and the parameter wouldn’t change on the left 9 times experiments.

Comment: Thanks so much:D The Most detailed answer I’ve ever seen ！

Answer (score 0):

Without reading the paper (please provide it), it seems like he partitioned the data into 2 parts randomly, trained on one part, validated on the other part and recorded the performance results. He did this 10 times and probably averaged his performance results afterwards.

Comment: Thanks! The link is:  people.csail.mit.edu/khosla/papers/www2014_khosla.pdf